# mgcv: How to identify exact knot values in a gam and gamm model?

Tags: r, mgcv

I am using gams to fit a resource selection function to identify energy development thresholds for migratory deer. My model looks like this:

```
m4 <-gam(used~ti(propwells_buff_res1500, bs = "cr", k = 5) +
ti(year, bs = "cr", k = 5) + 
ti(propwells_buff_res1500, year, bs = "cr", k = 5), 
family = binomial(link = "cloglog"), data=mov, gamma=1.4, method="ML")
```

used is animal used locations, propwells_buff_res1500 are randomly generated "available" points (buffered by 1500m radii circle) that have differing amounts of energy development within them. I've constrained knots to 5, however, I'd like to be able to extract exact knot values because it's my understanding that knot values represent threshold values...aka the percent of surface disturbance where animal use drops off.

I hope this makes sense. If it doesn't, all I want to know how to do is get knot values. From plot(m4) I can eyeball where the slope of my non-linear line starts to change, but it would be very helpful to know the exact values.

So far, I have tried:

```
smooth <- m4$smooth[[3]]

smooth$knots 
##this knot option isn't available to me, 
##I saw it in an old post from 2016, figured out that XP should replace knots

smooth$XP
##and all this returns is list()
```

I would truly appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the knots, you can extract the `xp` component of the marginal smooth terms (note it is lowercase `xp` as there is an `XP` at the top level of the smooth which is something else).

Here's an example

```
library('mgcv')
## simulate some data
set.seed(1729)
df <- gamSim(2) # this is a bivariate example
## fit the model
mod <- gam(y ~ ti(x, bs = 'cr', k = 5) + 
               ti(z, bs = 'cr', k = 5) +
               ti(x, z, bs = rep('cr', 2), k = 5),
           data = df$data, method = 'REML')
## extract the 3rd smooth
sm <- mod[['smooth']][[3]]
```

The marginal bases are in `sm$margin`, which is simply a list of two smooth objects:

```
r$> str(sm$margin, max = 1)                          
List of 2
 $ :List of 21
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "cr.smooth" "mgcv.smooth"
  ..- attr(*, "qrc")=List of 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
  ..- attr(*, "nCons")= int 1
 $ :List of 21
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "cr.smooth" "mgcv.smooth"
  ..- attr(*, "qrc")=List of 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
  ..- attr(*, "nCons")= int 1
```

Each of these has a `xp` component:

```
sm_x <- sm$margin[[1]]
sm_z <- sm$margin[[2]]
```

Hence the knots for the marginal CRS of `x` are:

```
r$> sm_x$xp
          0%          25%          50%          75%         100%
0.0005697084 0.2477067126 0.4704501621 0.7121602102 0.9960833385
```

and for `z` are

```
r$> sm_z$xp
         0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
0.007381999 0.244705125 0.488819070 0.717802322 0.991505836
```

Why these values? They are at the quintiles of the observed covariate values:

```
r$> with(df$data, quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, length = 5)))
          0%          25%          50%          75%         100%
0.0005697084 0.2477067126 0.4704501621 0.7121602102 0.9960833385
r$> with(df$data, quantile(z, probs = seq(0, 1, length = 5)))
         0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
0.007381999 0.244705125 0.488819070 0.717802322 0.991505836
```

Which is how *mgcv* places knots for the CRS basis. The exact locations can be recovered using `place.knots()`:

```
r$> with(df$data, place.knots(x, 5))
[1] 0.0005697084 0.2477067126 0.4704501621 0.7121602102 0.9960833385
r$> with(df$data, place.knots(z, 5))
[1] 0.007381999 0.244705125 0.488819070 0.717802322 0.991505836
```

but it is safer to pull the knots from the marginal smooth objects as a user could always specify knots via the `knots` argument to `gam()`.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I came back to this and it was super helpful to me. I have another question. I interacted surface disturbance with year, here--- ti(propwells_buff_res1500, year, bs = "cr", k = 5) --- to understand how selection for surface disturbance (propwells..) changes from year to year. I was able to generate plots for each year (17 years) but I am wondering if it is possible to get the knot values for each of those years??

Comment: There are no knots for each year; there's a set of knots over the covariate `year` but they don't vary at all. As the answer shows, you can extract the knots of the marginal bases from a `ti()` smooth, but they're static, they don;t change with covariate values.